# Arduino ESP8266 EEPROM commit() returns false

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to save the SSID and password in the EEPROM in my Arduino Sketch Wlan.

Actually everything works so far, except that the commit () returns a false. And that's why the memory is empty again after a restart.

My code:

```
void writePROM()
{
  EEPROM.begin(0);
  EEPROM.write(0, 0xAA);

  byte ssidLength = ssid.length();
  byte passLength = pass.length();

  int adress = 2;
  EEPROM.write(1, (byte)ssidLength);
  for(int i = 0; i < ssidLength; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(adress + i, (byte)ssid[i]);
  }
  adress += ssidLength + 1;

  EEPROM.write(adress++, passLength);
  for(int i = 0; i < passLength; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(adress + i, pass[i]);
  }

  bool bRc = EEPROM.commit();
  if(bRc)
  {
    Serial.println("Write successfully");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Write error");
  }
  
  
  Serial.println("Write name to EEPROM = " + ssid);
  Serial.println("Write password to EEPROM = " + pass);
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "What I am doing wrong?" Using a poor quality library that only returns true or false as error information. Could be anything: wrong prescaler clock, memory protection active, misalignment, timeout... step through the code with your debugger if you got the source of that poor lib, step into their functions and see where they go wrong.

Comment: the esp8266 saves this data by itself. try a sketch with WiFi.begin(ssid, pass) and then upload the same sketch with WiFi.begin() without the parameters. it will connect to remembered network. here is a simple ConfigurationAP example which uses this https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/ConfigurationAP/ConfigurationAP.ino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, good on you for checking the result of the `commit()` call.

You're passing 0 when you initialize the EEPROM library:

```
  EEPROM.begin(0);
```

You need to pass it the number of bytes that you're looking to store using it.

You can read the [code for the EEPROM library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp#L46) to confirm this:

```
void EEPROMClass::begin(size_t size) {
  if (size <= 0) {
    DEBUGV("EEPROMClass::begin error, size == 0\n");
    return;
  }
```

If you pass 0 it simply returns without doing any setup. You can also see that [`commit()` will do nothing](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp#L121) in this case:

```
bool EEPROMClass::commit() {
  if (!_size)
    return false;
```

In your case you should call `EEPROM.begin()` with at least the maximum size of an SSID and password plus one each for the zero terminating bytes (so, 32 characters for the SSID, 63 for the password, plus 2 for 97).

But, as @Juraj pointed out in the comments, you don't need to do any of this as the ESP8266 will automatically persist the Wifi credentials.